# How to close sidenav if clicked?

Tags: typescript, angular-material

I am making a responsive sidenav  using angular material but when I am clicking on any sidenav it is not closing .

HTML:

```
        <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill  class="example-container">

  <mat-sidenav style="width: 200px" color="primary" #sidenav fxLayout="column" mode="over"  opened="false" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
    <div fxLayout="column">
      
        <button mat-button routerLink="home" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Nunito';font-weight: 700;"><mat-icon>home</mat-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</button>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <button mat-button routerLink="attend" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Nunito';font-weight: 700;"><mat-icon>event</mat-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;Attend</button>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <button mat-button routerLink="host" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Nunito';font-weight: 700;"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;Host</button>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
     <span *ngIf="!(afAuth.authState| async)" style="text-align: center"><button  mat-button routerLink="login" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Nunito';font-weight: 700;"><mat-icon>login</mat-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;Login/Register</button></span> 
      <div style="margin-left: 85px; margin-top: 10px" >
          <ngx-auth-firebaseui-avatar [links]="links"
          [canViewAccount]=false
          canDeleteAccount=false
          (onSignOut)="signOut()"
          ></ngx-auth-firebaseui-avatar>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav>
```

What logic should I use in type script file to make  sidenav closed when clicked on it?
I am making a responsive sidenav  using angular material but when I am clicking on any sidenav it is not closing .

Answer (score 2):

On your `mat-sidenav`, you have to define a mouse click handler as follows:

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav (click)="closeSidenav()" ... >
```

In the component class, you need a [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) reference to your `mat-sidenav` and the implementation of the click handler method `closeSidenav()`.

```
@ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav;

closeSidenav(): void {
  this.sidenav.close();
}
```

If the method `closeSidenav()` does nothing else but closing the sidenav, you may also get rid of it and define the mouse click handler as follows:

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav (click)="sidenav.close()" ... >
```

Comment: I am getting one issue... cant find name MatSidenav

Comment: Add this to the component class:  `import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';`

Comment: but when I click on one of the elements of sidenav , it is not closing.. If i click outside the sidenav ,  sidenav is closing but when i click on one of the list in sidenav it is not closing after tha

Comment: In that case you should probably also add the same click event handler to the controls contained in your sidenav.